# Unable to load the requested class Session in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, libraries

My libraries in `autoload.php` is:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = 
     array('database','pagination','session','cart','form_validation');
```

I get this error:

```
An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested class: session
```

I'm using codeigniter version 3.0.

Comment: Can you please add error which you are getting.

Comment: I am getting this error:        An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: session

Comment: Have you set encryption key ?

Comment: yes, i fixed it but no solution

Comment: Try loading it as a driver, if a library is a folder you should call it like a driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all,

finally i found a solution,

I loaded this library like this:

```
$this->load->library('Session/session');
```

I used it because in codeigniter 3.0 the libraries files of session is located in the path :

```
System/libraries/Session/Session.php.
```

Now, it is working...

Answer (score 0):

Check encryption key in `config/config.php`. If not set then set encryption key in `config/config.php`

Comment: Try to load session on your controller method.

Comment: Here is my code in controller:
 function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
   
   $this->load->model('base_model');
   $this->load->database();
   $this->load->library('session');
 
    }

Comment: Try this public function  __construct() { parent::__construct();$this->load->database();$this->load->model('base_model');   } and On your method public function yourMethod(){ $this->load->library('session');}

Answer (score 0):

You must set encryption key in config/config.php before you use session class. As [official documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encrypt.html) described, please make sure about that when you choose encryption key,

> To take maximum advantage of the encryption algorithm, your key should
>   be 32 characters in length (128 bits). The key should be as random a
>   string as you can concoct, with numbers and uppercase and lowercase
>   letters. Your key should not be a simple text string. In order to be
>   cryptographically secure it needs to be as random as possible.

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: I set it like this :
$config['encryption_key'] = '12778a4ee106c41d2c0ad20cf2e4d1cd'; 
but no solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Unix/Linux, make sure to load your library with capital letters:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('Session');
                                ^
```

Also setting encryption key is important.

Comment: i am working on windows, and i already set encryption key. but nothing

Comment: which version of CI are you using??

Comment: I am using Codeigniter 3.0, if i add a session in libraries for loading then error occurs otherwise working fine but if session will not be loaded then it will not be work, so please help me...

Comment: from where did you downloaded the files??

Comment: i downloaded it from codeigniter personal website.                   https://www.codeigniter.com/download..

Answer (score 0):

Set encryption key in config.php

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'your_key';
```

Key can be anything
Hope your problem can be resolved
Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest version of CodeIgniter and only replaced the Session folder from system/libraries with my old folder and it worked without changing any other things.