# can't able to run codeigniter in linux 18.04 with nginx

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have my codeigniter application in my windows server. it works fine. But I tried to move to ubuntu environment. for that i am using WinSCP tool to move my codeigniter to my linux server. After that when i tried to run it shows error

> Unable to load the requested class: session.

I am using nginx, php 7.2 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I already tried the solutions given for 
Unable to load the requested class: session this one. I have 777 folder permission.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load the requested class Session in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729202/unable-to-load-the-requested-class-session-in-codeigniter)

Comment: I have tried but no luck

Comment: any solutions???????

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you load the session library in `autload.php`

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

> Make sure your encryption key is set in `cofing.php`

`$config['encryption_key'] = 'any random sequence here'`

> Make sure to load your library with capital letters

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('Session');`

In you config file inside `application/config/config.php` set the session variable to these values-

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']        = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']        = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']    = 300;
```

> If none of the above steps fix your problem then replace your system
>   folder with the system folder of a working project or download and do
>   a fresh install of Codeigniter from
>   http://www.codeigniter.com/download.